# Docker: Can't pick up config file for nginx on Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, windows-10

I have some configuration in docker-compose.yml file.

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - 8083:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - /c/xampp/htdocs/Drukwerk/rePortal:/var/www/html
        - /c/docker/reportal/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes:
        - /c/xampp/htdocs/Drukwerk/rePortal:/var/www/html
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/docker-data/reportal:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: reportal
        MYSQL_USER: reportal
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: reportal
```

And when I try to run `docker-compose up -d` I got this error message:

```
C:\docker\reportal>docker run --name reportalnginx -v /c/xampp/htdocs/Drukwerk/rePortal:/var/www/html:ro -v /nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -P -d nginx
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "/reportalnginx" is already in use by container 2e7427b8dd13515c9868cceb31e56b7cd10626feff7a561c1bc19eeaa1158f1c. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..
See 'docker run --help'.
```

But when I remove line with config file path for nginx - it works normal.

Also I've been trying to use hint from this question:
[Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900692/how-to-use-custom-nginx-config-for-official-nginx-docker-image?rq=1)
I was able to run nginx, but volumes wasn't connected.

How I can solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to remove all containers
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
and run again. or check you nginx in system. maybe you can stop it.

Comment: I found the decision. I've changed nginx config file path in volumes to `- ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro` and it works. BUT my application still doesn't work. I've checked the image of nginx and I've found that conf.d directory is empty. 
I've been trying to create config file but I got this error message:

`root@5be85fccbee6:/etc/nginx/conf.d# touch default.conf
touch: cannot touch 'default.conf': Read-only file system`